# How do I refresh tkinter window totally in python with a refresh button

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

**How do I refresh Tkinter window totally in python with a refresh button.**

Comment: Totally remove the window with all components and display it again.

Comment: @TamalChakraborty: you just answered your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to implement the entire window as a subclass of a tk Frame, and then destroy and recreate it. Your code might look something like this:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        <other code here...>

class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.frame = None
        refreshButton = tk.Button(self.root, text="refresh", command=self.refresh)
        self.refresh()

    def refresh(self):
        if self.frame is not None:
            self.frame.destroy()
        self.frame = Example(self.root)
        self.frame.grid(...)
```

Though,there's nothing really magical about subclassing Frame. You just need to have a function that creates a frame and puts a bunch of widgets in it. When you want to refresh, just delete the frame and call your function again. Using a class is a bit more convenient, but a class isn't strictly necessary.

Answer (score -2):

Try this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
r = tk.Tk()
r.title("refresh button")
def refresh():
    r.destroy()
    os.popen("refresh.py") #change refresh.py according to yours program name
button_1 = tk.Button(r,text = "Refresh",command = refresh)
button_1.pack()
def exit():
    r.destroy()
button_2 = tk.Button(r,text = "Exit",command = exit)
button_2.pack()
r.mainloop()
```