# How to refresh tkinter window in application

Tags: python, tkinter, window, refresh, frame

Subject was already covered before, but the solution for some reason does not work in my app.

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    menubar = tk.Menu(self)
    file_menu = tk.Menu(menubar)
    file_menu.add_command(label='Quit', command=sys.exit)
    menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file_menu)
    self.config(menu=menubar)

    self.frames = {}
    for F in (
              , choiceMenu
              , newEntry
              ):
        frame = F(container, self)
        self.frames[F] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(logging)

   def show_frame(self, c):
       frame = self.frames[c]
       frame.tkraise()


class newEntry(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        #adding some entries and labels here


    def newProd(self):
    #this function takes the entry values and uses them to amend the database (sqlite db);
    self.controller.show_frame(choiceMenu)


 class ViewOrd(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    label1=tk.Label(self,text='ID').grid(row=1,column=0)


    button = tk.Button(self, text="Back to menu",command=lambda: controller.show_frame(choiceMenu)).grid(column=2)
```

When I add a new order to the table in database (new row) I will not see any changes in ViewOrd frame (which displays all placed orders) until I rerun the whole app. How can I make my ViewOrd frame refresh and extract the amended version of table to show it to the user? The way of calling the refreshing function doesn't matter (button in the ViewOrd frame or automatic refreshing will do).

Comment: What solution did you try? Mention it, link it if it's an SO post. What went wrong with it? short answer: update_idletasks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507167/how-do-i-refresh-tkinter-window-totally-in-python-with-a-refresh-button I tried this one, but appearently the way of accessing frame within classes in my app is different.

Comment: This question is very answerable; I'd take a a trip to the help centre http://stackoverflow.com/help and read on minimal working examples and how to form a question that shows what you've already tried. I have a feeling you'll get an answer very quickly if you fix up this question a little :)

Comment: It seems to me you are fairly skillful in terms of python, would you explain a little bit more how to use this command to solve my particular problem? I've been googling it, but can't find anything helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to - but it'll be much easier for me to do so if the question is clearer; instead of your entire code dump can you reduce it to a few lines that reproduce the problem? For example, do we need 10 labels to reproduce the problem or just 1 label? Is that sqlite import necessary to reproduce the issue, because I don't have that module so I can't run your code to see your problem as long as it's there. Are the menus relevant? How about that complex gridding logic? Strip out the superfluous stuff and I'll be happy to help :) !!

Comment: I edited the code slightly, but the problem is I started programming only a few months ago, this is my first ever programme and I am not python literate and I am not certain what to erase and what to leave to keep the problem trackable. This is not full code though, just ~10% of it.

Comment: Great, thank you. That's much better - still some to trim, for sure, and learning how to debug will be really important, but I can take a crack at this now :)

Comment: Hmm right now it has errors though. I suggested you take out sqlite, but sqlite looks like it's being caled; if you take out the import then you also need to take out its usages or else the code doesn't run

Comment: Okay I erased that bit. I left it to make it easier to understand how the whole process of viewing table is realised, because I thought it may be useful for problem solving.

Comment: Okay, we're getting there, I've tried running it but two things are still making me unable to reproduce your problem: (1) your indentation is not valid; you should copy and paste your own codeblock into a text editor, run it, and make sure it compiles and reproduces your problem. (2) This code doesn't do anything. Something needs to be called, right? You define a bunch of classes but don't use them